# No encuentro el modulo tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

No se porque pero me da siempre el mismo error de

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

A pesar de ya estar instalado, uso pyton 3.9.1.

```
from tkinter import *

layout = Tk()

layout.mainloop()
```

Comment: lo has instalado?

Comment: si, hasta donde yo sabia era pip install tk y me aparece en la lista de los modulos pero me da el mismo error-

Comment: pues.... muchas veces viene instalado por defecto ._.